# "They be paid" or "they should be paid"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, be

Here is a sentence that I am trying to understand grammatically:-

> Defrauded depositors of XBANK staged a protest march from the New Town
>   hall to the Fountain circus this afternoon demanding that they be paid
>   immediately.

How can we just use:-

> they be paid

In my understanding, the correct way should be:-

> they should be paid immediately

Comment: [I demand they be {whatever it is you want done to them}](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+demand+they+be%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is perfectly normal English. If you want a simpler, more "idiomatic" version, those depositors could be *demanding **to be** paid immediately*, but I don't see anything grammatically unusual in your version. Nor do I see why changing plain "be" to "should be" makes any difference.

Comment: All 3 forms are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's fine. It's just a shortened version of "that they are to be paid immediately".

Comment: Can't it be shorten even further, dropping "that" ? "[...]  this afternoon demanding they be paid immediately."

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of the [subjunctive mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive). See several examples like yours [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive).

Comment: Could you explain how this is a subjunctive situation? In what manner is it subjunctive?

Comment: @Geek, it describes an Intention.